# Unable to Pass variable from html to php page using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a web form in which consists of a calendar and a submit button. On clicking this Submit button, I need to pass the value of selected date into another page. I am trying to achieve this using jquery. However it doesnt seem to be working.

I am not using the Post method in the form as I will have multiple submit buttons in this page.

My first page is form.php

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#submit').on("click", function(e){               
                var datevalue = $('#selecttime').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "displayer.php",
                    data: "value="+datevalue,

                    success: function(data) {
                            window.location.href = "displayer.php";
                    }
                });

            });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="datetime" >Select date and time:</label>
            <input type="text"  name = "selecttime" id="selecttime" size="30"/> <a href="javascript:NewCal('selecttime','ddmmyyyy',true)"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the second page, `displayer.php` I just want to display the date and time value that is passed from the first page and later continue with further processing.

```
$get_time = S_POST[value];
echo $get_time;
```

However this doesn't seem to be working even after trying to debug it for hours.

Please let me know where I have gone wrong and what needs to be modified.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your current code will make an AJAX call and then redirect to another page.

Comment: Have you opened the browser's dev tools and watched the request / response in the console?

Comment: Why not just use `action="displayer.php"` in the form and then access `$_POST['selecttime']`? An AJAX call is not what you want (displayer.php does not store the values you passed in the AJAX call).

Comment: instead of doing a window.location redirect, you should be doing a form submit. give your form a ID. then call $("#formiid").submit();

Comment: it should be $get_time = $_POST[value]; --> dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing AJAX with postback / full page refresh.

Currently, your code makes an AJAX request to displayer.php, does nothing with the data returned, and then redirects to displayer.php (defeating the purpose of AJAX). When you redirect, displayer.php does not remember the values you posted.

Try something like:

```
<body>
    <form action="displayer.php" method="post">
        <label for="datetime" >Select date and time:</label>
        <input type="text"  name = "selecttime" id="selecttime" size="30"/> <a href="javascript:NewCal('selecttime','ddmmyyyy',true)"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Which will post to displayer.php and load the page immediately.

Get rid of the click handler completely

Answer (score 0):

I am not using action="displayer.php" in the form tag, as I will be having multiple buttons on the same page. Every button click will have to perform different functions.

If above code is the wrong way of achieving this, could you please tell how I need to go about this. Basically I need to pass the value of the textbox to the next page' displayer.php' where it will be processed and saved to database.